# Parsing a SIP-packet .cap file to reach "INFO" field

Tags: python-3.x, sip, wireshark, packet-capture, tshark

I am trying to parse a pack of SIP-frames which are stored in a .cap file.
Everything seems to be working smoothly I read correct data but there is a small fault which I cannot overcome.

I need to get to the INFO field of each frame to get the information about number FROM which the number was dialled and also a TO field to know where the call was made to.

I gather data via dcpdump and store them in a .cap file. While reading the file via Wireshark I can see the field so I know that it was captured correctly. But I need to automate that process so I need to omit using WS.

I tried using tshark with known option -e col.Info (also col.info which is obviously incorrect) but I constantly get:

> tshark: Some fields aren't valid:
>   col.Info

My tshark version is 2.2.6 so it should be working as I read that it is valid in versions higher than 1.5 or somewhere around it.

I also tried ChaosReader to create a .html file and that also worked nicely still no info field though. 
Another way I tried was to use pcap2xml as I thought that an XML should contain ALL the data from the frame but that solution also lets me down.

I am running out of ideas so I came here for support and new suggestions.

Also: a way of parsing that data in Python would be also a plus as I want to process this data later using Python.
I tried Scapy but I was not able to obtain the data that I need.

Screen of the Wireshark capturing:
[image: Screen of the Wireshark capturing:]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SIP. Using a SIP pcap, I tried looking for the Info field, but I can't find any. Wireshark (v2.2.6) also doesn't seem to know it as a Display filter. It has `sip.Info-Package` though. What version of Wireshark are you using? Do you have an example of such a field (pcap or screen capture)?

Comment: @pchaingo please find screen attached. I am aim for the last field seen here (to the right)

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a column, not a field per Wireshark's terminology. I was looking for a field in the packets :-)
I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column field from Wireshark can be outputted by tshark using the **`-o column:format:"Info","%i"`** format. To output this column in addition to the to (`sip.to.addr`) and from (`sip.from.addr`) addresses of each SIP packet, you can run:

```
$ tshark -r input.pcap -o 'column.format:"Info","%i","From","%Cus:sip.from.addr","To","%Cus:sip.to.addr"' sip
Request: REGISTER sip:sip.cybercity.dk  (1 binding) |  sip:voi18063@sip.cybercity.dk sip:voi18063@sip.cybercity.dk
Status: 401 Unauthorized |  sip:voi18063@sip.cybercity.dk sip:voi18063@sip.cybercity.dk
Request: REGISTER sip:sip.cybercity.dk  (1 binding) |  sip:voi18063@sip.cybercity.dk sip:voi18063@sip.cybercity.dk
```

Comment: Bingo! That is precisely what I needed. I didn't know about %Cus keyword: can you give me source from which you got that way of filtering? Based on what I have found on tshark docs it is told to use another syntax.

Comment: `tshark -G column-formats` gives you all possible formats for `-o 'column.format:'`.

Comment: I am aware of that but please, take a look at the example that is there:
" tshark -o 'gui.column.format:"No.","%m","Time","%t","Source","%s","Destination","%d","Protocol","%p","Length","%L","Info","%i"' " - it is quite different than yours

Comment: Yes, but the list of possible formats contains `%Cus Custom` (7th line for me). That's where I got the `%Cus` syntax from.

Comment: FYI: The Wireshark internal application display filter prefix of "_ws." was introduced beginning with 1.12.0, so `-e col.Info` doesn't work after that release; instead you'll need to use `-e _ws.col.Info`.  This was mentioned in the Wireshark 1.12.0 release notes: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/relnotes/wireshark-1.12.0.html#_new_and_updated_features.  See also: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10201#c1

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard Thanks for the information! I don't think this applies to the `-o` format though. I tested the above locally with success using TShark 2.2.6 compiled from sources.

Comment: I provided the information to clarify your misuse of the field and as an alternate way to solve your problem if you wish, e.g.: `tshark -r input.pcap -T fields -e _ws.col.Info -e sip.from.addr -e sip.to.addr`.  Incidentally, `-o` is used to specify many options and not just the column format when printing columns instead of fields.

Comment: Oh, I see. You should probably post this as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

At the suggestion of pchaigno, I'm posting my earlier comment as an answer, edited a bit.

The Wireshark internal application display filter prefix of "`_ws.`" was introduced beginning with Wireshark 1.12.0, so `-e col.Info` doesn't work after that release; instead you'll need to use `-e _ws.col.Info`. This was mentioned in the [Wireshark 1.12.0 release notes](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/relnotes/wireshark-1.12.0.html#_new_and_updated_features).  See also [Comment 1 of Wireshark Bug 10201](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10201#c1).

This answer is provided as an alternate way to solve the problem, one that lends itself well to automation and scripting.  Here's an example:

```
tshark -r input.pcap -T fields -e _ws.col.Info -e sip.from.addr -e sip.to.addr
```

Refer to the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information, where `-e _ws.col.Info` is even used in one of the examples.